# Starting internal app on device start-up - iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, gps, voip

I have been trying to look into how I can automatically start(not into the foreground, just the background) an iOS app upon booting the device. The app itself will be used to send GPS location to a server periodically as soon as the device is started.

I understand that this is possible by declaring the app as a VOIP app and since this is an internal app, I am not worried about the app being rejected by Apple. There aren't many tutorials about how to do this since this is kind of a niche topic of iOS development.

My problem is that I am about 3 days old into objective-c programming and iOS development so I need someone to point me in the right direction. I've already finished writing the core functions of my app, and all that remains is to just get it to start upon boot or restart when terminated.

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how I would do this from a code standpoint?

Comment: read the introduction documemts that apple recommends, then read the LocationAwareNess Guide.

Comment: I've already read most of the documents on multitasking, background execution, VoIP apps and unfortunately haven't found too much :(. My question is, how can an VoIP app start itself in the background from a terminated state when the device boots?

Answer (score 0):

The app can't launch itself from the background.
The user have to first start the app.